# local variable, optimisation and ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

Given `NSArray *tagsArray` and `NSMutableDictionary *cache` not empty.

This:

```
for (Tag *tag in tagsArray) {
    NSString *name = tag.name;
    [cache setObject:tag forKey:name];
}
```

should not be slower than this:

```
for (Tag *tag in tagsArray) {
    [cache setObject:tag forKey:tag.name];
}
```

?

the __strong var 'name' would not use an implicit retain/release by ARC ? The compiler will actually generate the second from the first ?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were a difference in a release build, but in a debug build the retain/release would probably be there.

Comment: Yes these would compile to the exact same thing

Comment: *Should* compile to the exact same thing, probably. I wouldn't mind betting there's something odd going on though if you're seeing it actually being slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it IS the same for ARC, because there's no other code that interacts with "name" variable in first example.

For future, try to understand that ARC modifies your code for better performance and optimization, and not vice versa.

Here's the link with entire documentation for ARC - must know - http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html

Answer (score 0):

If ChildClass objecA, objecB.... has an instance variable, and ParentClass tries to assign the ChildClass's instance variable (which is an instance variable of ParentClass and strong pointer),

then ChildClass' object acts like the same object. Although it is not the same. Definitely not same.